# Are there any microphone access logs?

Tags: 9.0-pie, microphone

Is there a way to figure out when a microphone was active in the past and what app used it?

The requested timespan is 2 weeks and the device presumably was never in USB debugging. The device runs Android Pie (9).

My first idea was to extract logcat logs, but those are deleted once the device has been restarted, except for errors which are hold on for longer.

I'm currently researching with my personal device (Android 12). I can read my detailed `logcat` since the beginning of the device session (incl. all errors of this year) using:

```
adb logcat -d -T '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

But I cannot spot any entries that indicate my voice messages in Telegram, for instance. What do I have to look for? Unfortunately, this method is useless if the device was restarted recently, since I only can retrieve errors this way.

I can also print the last 50 events recorded by the `RecordActivityMonitor` using:

```
adb shell dumpsys audio
```

I probably need a few hundred times as many entries to retrieve the entire last 2 weeks, but I suspect that a restart would reset this log as well.

Comment: You can get a timestamp of when an app last used the microphone. History is stored in `/data/system/appops/history/`. Get it using `appops get <PKG> RECORD_AUDIO` or my app [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) (see [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246732/android-ftrace-microphone#comment330599_246732)).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes, I tested `appops get org.telegram.messenger.web RECORD_AUDIO` and sadly, this gives me only the last data plot, I really need all activity in the past 2 weeks, is there no other way?